# Create a class instance using a string containing the package name and class name

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible in Kotlin to create an instance of a class by providing just a string containing a package name and class name? I know that this can be done using Java:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.mydomain.myapp.someclass");
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```

But is there something more native to Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

```
val cls = Class.forName("com.mydomain.myapp.someclass").kotlin
```

gives you a `KClass<*>`, you can find everything it supports in https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html. If e.g. you know this is a Kotlin class with a primary constructor, you can do

```
val ctor = cls.primaryConstructor!!
val object = ctor.call(ctorArgument)
```

Or pick the constructor you want from `cls.constructors`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

Add the following to build.gradle:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

Create the instance as follows:

```
val classInstance = Class.forName("com.mydomain.myapp.someclass").kotlin.objectInstance
```

Comment: This doesn't create an instance, like your Java code does; this will only work if it's declared as an `object` and will return that object.