# Filter inside MemberProperties return error : Expected type mismatch: inferred type is KProperty1<out Any!, Any?>? but KProperty1<T, *>? was expected

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to create a inline function that can return entity column name, but get error when i try to filter list of memberProperties from a instance class that i create

This is the error i get :

```
Expected type mismatch: inferred type is KProperty1<out Any!, Any?>? but KProperty1<T, *>? was expected
```

i try the tutorial from this  [Create a class instance using a string containing the package name and class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59262723/create-a-class-instance-using-a-string-containing-the-package-name-and-class-name)

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "dbo")
data class Employee(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, length = 20)
    var id: String,

    @Column(name = "employee_name", nullable = true, length = 30)
    var employeeName: String? = "",

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_code", referencedColumnName = "dept_code", nullable = true)
    var dept: MasterDept? = null
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "ms_dept", schema = "dbo")
data class MasterDept(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "dept_code", nullable = false, length = 20)
    var code: String,

    @Column(name = "dept_desc", nullable = true, length = 100)
    var desc: String? = "",

@ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "div_code", referencedColumnName = "div_code", nullable = true)
        var div: MasterDiv? = null
    
    )

@Entity
    @Table(name = "ms_div", schema = "dbo")
    data class MasterDiv(
        @Id
        @Column(name = "div_code", nullable = false, length = 20)
        var code: String,
    
        @Column(name = "div_desc", nullable = true, length = 100)
        var desc: String? = ""
    
    )
```

i try to get column name from property desc of entity MasterDept or MasterDiv, depend of usage

here is my function :

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> getColumnName(filt:String):String {
    var listFilter:List<String> = listOf();
    if(filt.contains(".", true)){
        listFilter = filt.split(".")
        filt = listFilter.get(0)
    }

    var property = T::class.memberProperties.filter { prop -> prop.name == filt}.firstOrNull()//here is working 
    var colName : String = ""
var tableName:String = ""
    if(listFilter.size > 1){
        var idx:Int = 1
        
        for(item : String in listFilter) {
            if(idx < listFilter.size){
                val cls = Class.forName(property!!.returnType.toString()).kotlin
                var table = cls.annotations.find { it.annotationClass == Table::class } as? Table
                tableName = table!!.name

                property = cls.memberProperties.filter { prop -> prop.name == listFilter.get(idx)}.firstOrNull()  //error in here
            }
            idx++
        }
    }
    var field = property!!.javaField!!
    var column = field.getAnnotation(Column::class.java)
    return tableName + "." + column!!.name()
}
```

**filt** parameter sometimes is "employeeName", "dept.desc" or "dept.div.desc"

am i missing something??

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin is a strongly typed language. You can't declare a variable with a type `KProperty1<T, *>?` and reassign it with a value of type `KProperty1<out Any, *>?` (because the latter is not a subtype of the former). Actually, you haven't declared these types explicitly; they were inferred by the compiler.

Not sure what's going on in this code (and if it is possible to avoid mutation of the `property` variable, which is preferrable), but you can fix this error by declaring `property`'s type as `KProperty1<*, *>?`, which is a supertype of all other `KProperty1` types; also its declaration could be simplified:

```kotlin
var property: KProperty1<*, *>? = T::class.memberProperties.firstOrNull { it.name == filt }
```

Comment: Thanks, do i need to import something?

Comment: Yes, you need to import `kotlin.reflect.KProperty1` (if it was not imported before). I'd recommend to use IDE (for instance, [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)), which will handle all imports for you (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html)